std::move captured unique_ptr inside lambda
I wanted to capture std::unique_ptr into lambda and then move it into another function inside lambda, but my two minimal examples fail to compile and I'm not sure why.
Can somebody explain to me, why it tries to make a copy even though I'm trying to move it in in first example and where does const qualifier comes from in second example?
First example (function accepts std::unique_ptr by value):
#include <memory>

void sink(std::unique_ptr<int> p) {
    // Do something with `p`
}

int main() {
    auto p = std::make_unique<int>(42);
    auto f = [p = std::move(p)](){
        sink(std::move(p));
    };
    f();
    return 0;
}

The error is:
<source>:10:13: error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>]'
   10 |         sink(std::move(p));
      |         ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/memory:78,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:516:7: note: declared here
  516 |       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
<source>:10:13: note: use '-fdiagnostics-all-candidates' to display considered candidates
   10 |         sink(std::move(p));
      |         ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:3:32: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void sink(std::unique_ptr<int>)'
    3 | void sink(std::unique_ptr<int> p) {
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
Compiler returned: 1

Second example (function accepts std::unique_ptr by rvalue ref):
#include <memory>

void sink(std::unique_ptr<int> &&p) {
    // Do something with `p`
}

int main() {
    auto p = std::make_unique<int>(42);
    auto f = [p = std::move(p)](){
        sink(std::move(p));
    };
    f();
    return 0;
}

The error is:
<source>: In lambda function:
<source>:10:23: error: binding reference of type 'std::unique_ptr<int>&&' to 'std::remove_reference<const std::unique_ptr<int>&>::type' {aka 'const std::unique_ptr<int>'} discards qualifiers
   10 |         sink(std::move(p));
      |              ~~~~~~~~~^~~
<source>:3:34: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void sink(std::unique_ptr<int>&&)'
    3 | void sink(std::unique_ptr<int> &&p) {
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
Compiler returned: 1


Remember that std::move does not actually move anything. It is merely a cast to rvalue reference - what then happens to that reference is up to the recipient.

@JesperJuhl Yeah, but std::move of std::unique_ptr into function works outside lambda, so why it doesn't work IN lambda?

Lambda members, the captures, are treated as const in the lambda body since the synthsized operatror() is const.  One way to get around that is to make the lambda mutable like
#include <memory>

void sink(std::unique_ptr<int> p) {
    // Do something with `p`
}

int main() {
    auto p = std::make_unique<int>(42);
    auto f = [p = std::move(p)]() mutable {
        sink(std::move(p));
    };
    f();
    return 0;
}

and then it will compile.

Interesting - so the main practical difference between the assignment from p = std::move(p) here and the capture of the reference in Remy's answer is that the original smart pointer is disposed of during assignment on definition of the lambda here, while the original smart pointer isn't disposed of in Remy's answer until the lambda is called. I had not thought through that before.

@DavidC.Rankin define "disposed of". When capturing unique_ptr by reference something in the outside world has to maintain its validity. Capturing by move ensures the lambda actually owns the unique_ptr and therefore the resource it manages.

@alagner std::unique_ptr - cppreference.com - that "disposed of". (when the deleter is called)

@DavidC.Rankin ok, clear enough. But please note, that cppreference mentions that the object managed by unique_ptr (not the smart pointer itself) is disposed of, that’s the reason behind my question, as the devil is oftentimes in the details. And yes, I’m being a bit picky  ;-)

The errors suggest (and the 2nd error explicitly states) that the named capture p is a const member of the lambda object. You can't move a const object, hence why a copy is attempted when passing p to sink(), and thus the failures.
If you capture the unique_ptr by reference without an initializer, the errors go away.
#include <memory>

void sink(std::unique_ptr<int> p) {
    // Do something with `p`
}

int main() {
    auto p = std::make_unique<int>(42);
    auto f = [&](){ // or: [&p]
        sink(std::move(p));
    };
    f();
    return 0;
}

